# Fill <input> element with <title> tag contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the element with `id="title-of-page"` I would like to set the contents of `value` to equal the contents of `<title>`

Here's the HTML I'm using

```
<input type="text" name="your-name" value=""  id="title-of-page">
```

I've tried using this Javascript but it doesn't seem to work

```
<script>
var $itemSearch = $('#page-title-form');
$itemSearch.val($itemSearch.attr('title'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#page-title-form').val($('title').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of the `<title>` element, not the input.

If you have a `<title>` element, you probably want it's text content, if it's the document title, you could just use `document.title` instead

```
var $itemSearch = $('#page-title-form');
$('#title-of-page').val($itemSearch.text());
// or
$('#title-of-page').val( document.title );
```